# Using raster graphics in Qt 4.7 on mac osx leads to memory leaks?

Tags: macos, qt, qt4

I'm having a problem with the using raster graphics (  QApplication::setGraphicsSystem("raster") ) on mac osx. The mac developer instruments tool is detecting memory leaks in my program of object type CGContext.  If I change the graphics system back to native I see no such leaks.  Is this really a memory leak? and if so, is there anyway to fix it?  The raster graphics perform so much better than the native ones, and I would like to continue using them.

P.S. If you want to duplicate this you can just open any of the demo programs in Qt Creator and add the line 'QApplication::setGraphicsSystem("raster")' right above where the QApplication is created.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd open up a bug report for this:

https://bugreports.qt.io/secure/Dashboard.jspa

I have found a problem with the graphics system on Qt and Mac in the past.  With someone easily reproducible they are likely to get back to you very quickly.

Comment: Thanks Phil, I actually just tried compiling my program with the new Qt 4.8 release candidate and the memory leaks disappeared.  I noticed that now 'raster' is the default graphics system on mac, so it looks like they fixed this.